# store references to arrays in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have a few arrays like this

```
var arr1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']   //array of strings
var arr2 = ['name4', 'name5', 'name6']
var arr3 = [....]
```

Now i wanted to convert each of the above array of strings into array of objects like

```
arr1 = [{name: 'name1'}, {name:'name2'}, {name:'name3'}]
```

Similarly for the other 2 arrays

So i came up with this

```
var bigArray = [arr1, arr2, arr3]
bigArray.forEach(function(arr, index, bigArray) {
     bigArray[index] = arr.map(function(item) {       // here i am assigning to current element of bigArray
     return {
           name: item
           };
     });
});
```

As you see while doing a `forEach` on `bigArray` and i modify each of its array(`arr1`, `arr2`,...) through a map.

After this `forEach`, `bigArray` looks like

```
[
   [{name: 'name1'}, {name:'name2'}, {name:'name3'}],
   [{name: 'name4'}, {name:'name5'}, {name:'name6'}],
   ....
]
```

but `arr1` is still `['name1', 'name2', 'name3']` and `arr2` is still `['name4', 'name5', 'name6']`

What i understand here is that `bigArray` does not contain references to `arr1`, `arr2`, .... Any idea how can i pass references? Or am i missing something else?

EDIT: I guess i couldnt explain myself clearly, so here it is--------
The reason i create `bigArray` is that i have too many of `arr1`, `arr2`, ... so i dont want to go and apply map over each of these individually so i put them i a big array called `bigArray` and do a `forEach` on them

Comment: What do yo mean a reference? You want it so if you change something in the bigArray it changes the original?

Comment: @epascarello exactly.

Comment: Yeah, not going to happen since mapping it is making a new copy and there is no way to link them.

Comment: just work on the indexes and it will work, http://jsbin.com/OXeNORE/2/

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks. This works but i dont think there is an issue with the index. The reason i guess is that i pass the bigArray as third parameter to forEach which is passed as value and i modify that copy of bigArray hence the change is not reflected in arr1, arr2. But thanks a lot. Write it as an answer so i can mark it as accepted

Comment: @lovesh there is no *passed as value* in javascript (except for literals). So the inner arrays are truly `arr1` and `arr2` and so on. The problem is, that you overwrite the reference to those arrays the moment you assign the return value of array map (which returns a new array) to `bigArray[index]`. So by working on the indexes directly you keep all references intact.

Answer (score 2):

The [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method is what you want; this creates a **new array**, which is why you're seeing the results you are.

```
var arr1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']; 

var arrNames = arr1.map(function(nm){ return { name: nm }; });
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VEtb8/)

Again, `map` will not modify the array in question, that's why arr1 is not changed in your example. It simply *maps* the array to a new array, and returns that.

If you want to *change* the array in question, you need to do something like this:

```
var arr1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
arr1 = arr1.map(function(nm){ return { name: nm }; });

var arr2 ....
```

And then to have bigArray contain references to arr1, arr2, and arr3, you'd just create bigArray containing references to these arrays **after they've been properly defined**.

```
var bigArray = [arr1, arr2, arr3]
```

---

Last edit

If you really just want to save some key strokes, you could do something like this:

```
var arr1 = mapThis(['name1', 'name2', 'name3']);
var arr2 = mapThis(...
//and so on

function mapThis(arr){
    return arr.map(function(nm){ return { name: nm }; });
}
```

That'll create all your arrX arrays correctly from the start without too many extra key strokes.

Comment: I am already using the map method to modify each of `arr1`, `arr2`, ..  But what if i have 20 such arrays. I dont want to modify each array individually. So the `bigArray`

Comment: i know map wont modify `arr1` that is why you see in `forEach` i am modifying the `bigArray`. Read my comment in the code

Comment: @lovesh - see my edit.  The reason arr1 is not changes is because map does not change the underlying array

Comment: @lovesh - use map to set arr1 to however you want, then create bigArray from them.  See my last edit

Comment: Please read the edit section in my question. That might clarify my intention

Comment: @lovesh - I just did.  There's really not much to offer here.  You can use forEach to iterate over each arr1, arr2, and manually change each index therein, but then you'd just be manually doing what map does, so you might as well just call map for each one.

Comment: You see what i was really trying to save some keystrokes(trying to type less) there not thinking about performance which btw wont be different in either case

Comment: @lovesh - see my last edit - might be useful for you

Comment: Just think what would happen if i had 20 more arrays like arr1. Now i have to write this map function 20 times for each arr1. To avoid this i put those 20 `arr1`s in a big array and iterate over the big array and in each iteration i do a map on the arr1. so i just have to write the map function once

Comment: @lovesh - right.  That's how I would do it.  Then bigArray will contain what you want.  But your underlying arrX arrays will be unchanged.  If that's not acceptable, then you need to make sure your arrX arrays are created properly from the start.  There aren't really any other choices here.  Also, you don't have to *write* this map function 20 times, you just have to *call it* 20 times.

Comment: sorry. i meant call it 20 times

Answer (score 0):

solution without map. It will work in all browser.

```
var arr1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
var arr2 = [], i;

while(i = arr1.shift()) {
    arr2.push({"name": i});
}
arr1 = arr2;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation at MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), the map function `Creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.` You cannot operate on the original array using `map()` by itself, so you will need to assign the result of `map()` to `arr1` or another array and use that array where you need the change to be.

You can do something like this, without `map()` to push a ton of arrays:

```
var bigArray = [arr1, arr2, arr3];
var bigArrayFinal = [];
var nextArray;
while(nextArray = bigArray.slice()) {
  var thisArray = [];
  var nextElement;
  while(nextElement = bigArray.slice()) {
    thisArray.push({"name": nextElement});
  }
  bigArrayFinal.push(thisArray);
}
```